# VSCode autoAttach showing node internals

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm struggling to debug asynchronous code in VS code because I keep going in to async_hooks.js. I can see that using launch.json I can use skipFiles to resolve this issue.

However I'm loving using the auto attach feature of VS code and this does not seem to have a launch config. Is there any way to configure VS code to skip internal functions I don't care about and use the auto attach feature?

Answer (score 1):

> this is not yet possible (but planned).

See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/55947.